# Rapidminer Neural Network Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-modeling, forecasting, rapidminer

I'm using a NN model for demand forecasting, and I'm curious if anyone knows what kind of accuracy is reasonable to expect from the model itself. In the industry I'm in, we're able to do pretty well with forecasting error (5-10%), and the model I currently have is at 86% accuracy. I'm not an expert in NN modeling, but my intuition is telling me that a 14% error in the model validation doesn't necessarily correspond to a 14% forecasting error on average. If anyone has experience with these, what sort of accuracy is attainable/reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely problem dependent. We have no knowledge of what your problem even is, let alone data quality, amount, familiarity what how modern Rapid Miner's NN facilities are, validation / test set construction, and other potential issues.

> my intuition is telling me that a 14% error in the model validation doesn't necessarily correspond to a 14% forecasting error on average.

If by forecasting you mean real / deployed error: generally, you should never expect the validation error to be lower than your true error. Validation is at best an accurate estimate of your true generalization, and at worst, a over-estimate due to some shared bias.